# Почему не работает QTimer?

Tags: python, pyqt5, многопоточность, qthread, qtimer

Кнопка `btn` - единственный виджет окна. Она привязана к методу `new_thread()`, который создает новый поток.

Внутри потока есть метод `func_1()`. Он должен три раза создать таймер, срабатывание которого должно привести к вызыву метода `func_2()`. 
Почему-то код метода `func_2()` не выполняется. 
Пожалуйста, подскажите, что я делаю неправильно?

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets

class MyThread(QtCore.QThread):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtCore.QThread.__init__(self, parent)

    def run(self):
        print('THREAD: run')
        self.func_1()

    def func_1(self):
        for i in range(0, 3):
            print('a')
            QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(150, self.func_2)

    def func_2(self):
        print('This doesn`t work :(')


class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        box = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)

        btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Button', clicked = self.new_thread)
        box.addWidget(btn)

    def new_thread(self):
        self.mythread = MyThread()
        self.mythread.started.connect(self.on_started)
        self.mythread.finished.connect(self.on_finished)
        self.mythread.start()

    def on_started(self):
        print('THREAD: start')

    def on_finished(self):
        print('THREAD: finish')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyWindow()
    window.setWindowTitle(' ')
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

**UPD**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets

class MyThread(QtCore.QThread):
    singlTimer = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtCore.QThread.__init__(self, parent)

    def run(self):
        print('THREAD: run')
        self.func_1()

    def func_1(self):
        for i in range(0, 3):
            print('a')
            self.singlTimer.emit()

    def on_singlTimer(self):
        QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(150, self.func_2)

    def func_2(self):
        print('This doesn`t work :)')


class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        box = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)

        btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Button', clicked = self.new_thread)
        box.addWidget(btn)

    def new_thread(self):
        self.mythread = MyThread()
        self.mythread.started.connect(self.on_started)
        self.mythread.finished.connect(self.on_finished)

        self.mythread.singlTimer.connect(self.mythread.on_singlTimer)

        self.mythread.start()

    def on_started(self):
        print('THREAD: start')

    def on_finished(self):
        print('THREAD: finish')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyWindow()
    window.setWindowTitle(' ')
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я думаю, что правильно сделать так:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets


class MyThread(QtCore.QThread):
    singlTimer = QtCore.pyqtSignal()                           # +++

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtCore.QThread.__init__(self, parent)

    def run(self):
        print('THREAD: run')
        self.func_1()

    def func_1(self):
        for i in range(0, 3):
            print('a')
#            QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(150, self.func_2)
            self.singlTimer.emit()                             # +++

#    def func_2(self):
#        print('This doesn`t work :(')


class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        box = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)

        btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Button', clicked = self.new_thread)
        box.addWidget(btn)

    def new_thread(self):
        self.mythread = MyThread()
        self.mythread.started.connect(self.on_started)
        self.mythread.finished.connect(self.on_finished)

        self.mythread.singlTimer.connect(self.on_singlTimer)            # +++

        self.mythread.start()

    def on_started(self):
        print('THREAD: start')

    def on_finished(self):
        print('THREAD: finish')

    def on_singlTimer(self):                                            # +++
        QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(150, self.func_2)

    def func_2(self):                                                   # +++
        print('This doesn`t work :)')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyWindow()
    window.setWindowTitle(' ')
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Большое спасибо! Мне бы желательно оставить `func_2` внутри класса `MyThread`. Я немного изменил ваш код и добавил его в вопрос. Как вы считаете, корректно ли так делать?

Comment: @MAXIM045 что вы собираетесь делать в методе `func_2`  и методе `func_1` ?

Comment: У меня есть два класса - `MyWindow` и `MyThread`. В `MyWindow` создаются все виджеты, в их числе кнопка выбора папки. Т.к. обработка тегов файлов может занимать минуты времени(если выбрать в качестве папки весь диск), мне необходимо вывести всю работу с извлечением характеристик аудиофайлов в другой поток. В `MyWindow` будет создаваться новый поток, если по нажатию на кнопку была выбрана какая-нибудь папка. В `func_1` я планировал извлекать из файла некоторые теги, создавать новый `QMediaPlayer` и таймер, привязанный к `func_2`. В `func_2` должна измерятся длительность аудиофайла

Comment: Если получилось как всегда непонятно, я попытаюсь объяснить нормально в обновлении вопроса

Comment: @MAXIM045 я практик, поэтому я вам предлагаю все ваши рассуждения положить в код и задать новый вопрос. Когда я увижу что и где происходит,  тогда и обсудим.

Comment: Тогда мой код будет достигать, наверное, около двухсот строк. Я правильно понимаю, что лучше ничего не сокращать?

Comment: @MAXIM045 да, делайте реальный пример.

Comment: Только извлечение тегов(название песни, альбома, артист) из MP3-файла с помощью модуля `mutagen`, наверное, стоит вырезать?

Comment: @MAXIM045 Мы начинали говорить о наполнении класса `MyThread` (методы func_2 и  func_1 ) остальное как-то можете опустить, если получится. The End.